# How to make continuous interaction from client to server in Java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

How to make continuous interaction from client to server in Java socket programming. Here in my program i have many folders in a directory ie) F://read and i am transferring folders with files from client to server. when at first request, one folder is transferred to the server from client and when it comes again to the client to send an another folder it's keep saying exception, java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed in the write() method of ClientProgram where i call socket.getOutputStream(). So please tell me how to resolve this problem. I think i want to use thread for each transmission, so please tell where i have to use to run this fine. Very much thank's.

Client code:

At each time forward method and write method passing data's from client to server. and listf(String directoryName) method running recursively for files and folders, when it finds folder it call's forward()and write() method. the forward() is to pass the directory path of the particular folder and write() method is to write all files here in client and passes to server at each time by the listf(String directoryName). at first time this method running fine. when at the second time again it calls write() mothod, there its giving java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed.why its happening.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ClientProgram extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ClientProgram() {
        super();
    }
    Socket socket;
    ClientProgram clientProgram;
    String hostDomain = "192.168.1.19";
    int port = 5855;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    FileInputStream fis;
    PrintStream pr;
    BufferedReader gt;
    List<File> resultList;

    public static listf(String directoryName) throws IOException {
        try {
            File directory = new File(directoryName);
            resultList = new ArrayList<File>();
            // get all the files from a directory
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
            resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
            for (File file : fList) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    System.out.println("file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    String pathtomake = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    System.out.println("folder now: " + pathtomake);
                    forward(pathtomake);
                    write(pathtomake);
                    System.out.println("folder: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    listf(file.getAbsolutePath());

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (dos != null) {
                dos.close();
            }
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public void write(String rec) throws IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("rr");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
            File file1 = new File(rec);
            File[] fil_Files_list = file1.listFiles();
            dos.writeInt(fil_Files_list.length);
            System.out.println("file will ..");
            for (File file : fil_Files_list) {
                long length = file.length();
                dos.writeLong(length);
                String name = file.getName();
                dos.writeUTF(name);
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                System.out.println("writin..");
                int theByte = 0;
                while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    bos.write(theByte);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public void forward(String drc) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        boolean b = socket.isConnected();
        System.out.println("Socket Is active or not: " + b);
        pr = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        pr.println(drc);
        gt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String tm = gt.readLine();
        System.out.print(tm);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket(hostDomain, port);
        String directory = "F://read";
        listf(directory);

    }

}
```

Server Code:

This is my server code accept to receive folders with files. here i am receiving folder path using BufferedReader from client method called forward() and adding to the detination path ie)d://save. after that i am writing all the files to the particular folder from client method called write().

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServerProgram extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ServerProgram() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    BufferedReader ed;
    PrintStream pr;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    DataInputStream dis;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    Socket socket;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println(1);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5792);
            System.out.println(2);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String tmp = ed.readLine();
            System.out.print("I Recieved :" + tmp);
            pr = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            String str = "Yup I got it !!";
            pr.println(str);
            int g = tmp.indexOf("\\");
            String di = tmp.substring(g);
            String dirPath = "D://save//" + di;
            System.out.println(dirPath);
            File file = new File(dirPath);
            JavaHeapMemory();

            if (file.exists() || file.mkdirs()) {
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                int filesCount = dis.readInt();
                File[] files = new File[filesCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
                    long fileLength = dis.readLong();
                    String fileName = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("name of the file: " + fileName);
                    files[i] = new File(dirPath + "/" + fileName);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    for (int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) {
                        bos.write(bis.read());
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
            if (dis != null) {
                dis.close();
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

    public void JavaHeapMemory() {
        long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        System.out.println("Heap Size = " + heapSize);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
            java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
                at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
                at pack.ClientProgram.forward()
```

In this above client program i used to transfer folders to the server recursively. but its not running in continuously from client to server.so please tell me the way to do this. i am very much thankful.

Answer (score 2):

You canot mix text and binary without the likelihood of confusion.

```
  ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

This means the BufferedReader can read as much data as it likes, not just how much you ask for.

```
  bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

This will start reading binary at some random point that the BufferedReader didn't read (not the amount you asked for)

In short, only use binary or text for a stream unless you really know what you are doing.

---

Your program has

```
while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
      bos.write(theByte);
```

This means, read until the end of the stream.  It also means it will read all data sent until the connection is closed.

If you want to send multiple files in the same stream, you need another way for the receiver to know when the file ended.  The simplest approach is to send the file size first, and have the reciever only read that much data.

BTW reading one byte at a time is *very* slow.  I suggest you read into a byte[] of say size 4KB.