# DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()); throwing connection refused exception

Tags: java, json, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post some data into the server. I am using a sample url whichis available online. I am not able to proceed further because the line,

`DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());`, is throwing Connection Refused Exception.
This is the code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("id", 5);

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(jsonObj.toString());
        os.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        String output;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);
            break;
        } 

        System.out.println("Response Code: "+responseCode);
        System.out.println("URL: "+url);
        System.out.println("Parameters: "+jsonObj.toString());
        System.out.println("Output: "+output.toString());

        con.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the Exception..

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at insertData.main(insertData.java:37)
```

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Your Server is not reachable

Comment: What server are you talking about?

Comment: `my-json-server.typicode.com/`

Comment: Server seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: How you know it?

Comment: I tried running the url in chrome.

Comment: Chrome has Proxy configuration. Your Java application not.

Comment: Can you please help me to configure?

Comment: Google `Java HttpURLConnection Proxy`

Comment: Maby this can help you a bit [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027919/how-to-make-continuous-interaction-from-client-to-server-in-java-socket-programm)

Comment: Can anyone please provide a working code for this problem because after trying few proxy solutions, it throws different exceptions everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your BufferedReader to BufferedInputStream also the "while" loop that you have is constructed in a wrong way so far as i can see, follow the link in my previous comment